# Can't view source in eclipse debug perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, perspective

I was moving around the arrangement of windows in the debug perspective. Afterwards, no matter which .java files I had open in the Java perspective, only the source file with the main method would be open in the debug perspective and I couldn't figure out how to see the other source files.

Then, I accidently closed the main source file and now I don't see any source code in my debug perspective.

If I go to Window -> New Editor, or if I double click on Main.java from the navigator, nothing happens.

I reset the perspective to default and in the editor, it says "No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.ui.internal.emptyEditorTab"

Comment: Do you have `Project Explorer` window open?

Comment: Go to Window ->Show View-> Package Explorer ?

Comment: I tried opening the files from project explorer and package explorer and nothing happens

Answer (score 5):

try this based on this [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386648),

Closing eclipse and removing .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

from your workspace, if you aware of another error, cut and paste to another location..

```
                 YOU CAN POST YOUR BUG TO THAT LINK 

     IF YOU FEEL THAT THAT BUG DOES NOT REPRESENT YOUR PROBLEM.. ^^

               FEEL FREE TO DO IT, THEY WILL HEAR YOU..
```

if you still want to worked with eclipse, re-install again, import your code. It worked against me. happy coding.. ^^

Answer (score 5):

I cut the file workbench.xmi --> C:\User\workspace.metadata.plugins\workbench.xmi

Now the eclipse is running without the Error!

Answer (score 2):

Delete workbench.xmi, it worked for me.